# Unable to add to NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, segmentation-fault

I can't seem to be able to add objects to an `NSMutableArray`. I create a mutable array, add an object to it and then try to iterate over it, or get its count but my program seg faults.

```
@interface myclass : NSObject
{
    NSString* aname;
}
@property (retain) NSString* aname;
@end

@implementation myclass
@synthesize aname;
@end

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    myclass* cls = [[myclass alloc] init];
    [cls setAname:@"myname"];
    NSMutableArray* arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"allocated array %@", [arr count]);
    [arr addObject:cls];
    NSLog(@"count %d", [arr count]);
}
```

Program crashes at the second `NSLog`. What's wrong?

Comment: Remove the @end after the @synthesize at least…

Comment: The function where the array is being created is not part of the class. Have renamed it to `main` to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an integer, returned from [arr count], to the log formatter, but telling NSLog to treat it as an NSObject (using "%@").  Try using "%d" instead.

Comment: That's not it.. Using `%d` does not fix it. Have updated question to use `%d`.

Comment: You still have the problem in the first NSLog call.

Comment: Even with the bad first NSLog, the program you listed works for me:


2011-03-21 01:24:28.859 tmp[26157:207] allocated array (null)
2011-03-21 01:24:28.861 tmp[26157:207] count 1

Comment: All I can think of is that first NSLog call with %@ might be screwing up the stack on your system, though it works fine for me.  I sometimes get weird results with bad NSLog calls.  The rest of the code looks fine.

Comment: You might also want to call initWithCapacity: on the NSMutableArray instead of just "init", which will bypass the NSMutableArray and call the constructor for the underlying NSObject.

Comment: I mean, either initializer should work, but I'd be curious to see if just calling init trips some sort of subtle bug in the implementation.

Comment: +1 The program works fine for me too as it is. Although, it is an `unsigned long` (`NSUInteger`) so the formatting code should be be `%lu` not `%d`.